# Why is there a delay when I unlock Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

When I wake my computer, there is a 5-10 second delay before I can type or move the mouse.

I've disabled the Lock Screen, but that didn't change anything. I don't remember this being an issue with Windows 7.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

> Edition: Windows 10 Pro x64
>   Processor: Intel Core i7-4810MQ
>   RAM: 8 GB
>   Storage: Samsung 850 Pro 256 GB

Comment: maybe it puts the usb ports or devices to sleep to save energy.

Comment: Check whether your HDD goes to power off state on sleep or not

Comment: Is it set to sleep or hibernate?  Hibernation takes longer because everything has to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. And solved (for me)!

Check USB power (just look at the visible light from the mouse: yes, present). Check HD power up: my SSD gives response without delay. Then check this: how many mouse drivers are present? Check in devices your mouse, show hidden devices (tab option), remove all unused mouse drivers, or delete all mouse drivers: Windows will restore them automatically.

After restart of the computer the problem was gone (on my computer). Success.

Comment: A USB hub was the problem in my case: https://superuser.com/a/1444918/74576

Answer (score 0):

Check screen saver settings. Ensure that "On resume display logon screen" is checked

Settings > Personalization > Screen saver settings > screen saver > check On resume display logon screen

if this settings is grayed you must delete "ScreenSaverIsSecure" using regedit

Key is in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop

Hope this help someone....

Comment: The question says that it was tested with the lock screen disabled.  It isn't clear how this applies.