# Windows 10 login screen has become very slow since recently

Tags: windows, windows-10, login-screen

## Slow Login-Screen

I haven't noticed when exactly I started observing the extreme slow down of the Windows 10 login screen on my laptop.

Sometimes, this screen is fast as it was normally; but once in a while after pressing the power button I have to wait about 5(!) minutes staring at pre-login screen. *I apologize for phone made images of the screen.*

[image]

In addition to that, the responsiveness has decreased dramatically. The reaction to button press is delayed by approximately 1-2 seconds!

[image]

After I enter my 4-digit PIN-code, I wait for about another minute for the Desktop to appear... What on Earth can cause that and where do I start troubleshooting? I inspected the Task Manager for any CPU hungry processes and disabled Windows Defender (yes, I know...) which was consuming a LOT of resources. That did not help much...

[image]

## Relevant notes

- I am not 100% sure, but I think that the extremely slow logins happen after my laptop is asleep for more than 4-6-8 hours ("deep hibernation" may be?) If I put the laptop to sleep and come back within an hour, it usually behaves nicely.
- The laptop is roughly 5 years old: **Samsung XE700T1C-H01RU**

  - Intel i5-3317U, 2 cores @ 1.7GHz
  - 4 GB DDR3 RAM @ 1600MHz
  - Samsung MZMTD128HAFV 128Gb SATA Gen3 / mSATA 6Gbps SSD
- When login is slow, after-login experience are slow as well for a few minutes. In less than 5 minutes the machine is fully functional again.
- I could not directly associate slow logins to any OS update related activities, but that's not easy to do in the first place.
- `winver`: **Windows 1607 OS Build 14393.1884**

**Update 1** [QuickSearch](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+login+is+slow+on+1607&oq=windows+login+is+slow+on+1607&aqs=chrome..69i57.2801j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows that there are many more users on `1607` version who experience same issue.

Comment: I also see this in 1607 on my tablet. seems to be an issue with one of the last updates.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy for the past week or so. **Then I remembered that a recent change I'd made was plugging my USB keyboard into a USB hub instead of straight into the back of the PC.**

Once I switched back (no longer using the hub), the lock screen doesn't have a delay, and I can type my password in immediately.

So the root cause was that the USB hub must have been slow.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Application event log.

In my case, I had warnings with event IDs 6005 and 6006 from Winlogon source, logged every startup:

> The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> is taking long time to handle the notification event (Logon).
> The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> took 70 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon).

The fix was simple, remove all data from `%TEMP%` folder.
I had around 100GB of some data there, and the logon time went down from 75 to 5 seconds.